# Is is "o.k." to skip OAuth2 in google spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, vba

I am working on a simple Google Docs spreadsheet plugin where the user needs to authenticate themselves with our server, then they can download data, etc. (Much like Bloomberg does in Excel). Looking through the docs for Google spreadsheets, they say that OAuth2 is the only way to authenticate with a google service (e.g. Youtube, etc...). Makes sense, since I (the "developer middleman") could intercept their credentials.

For my case, however, the only two parties involved is the user of the spreadsheet and our server. In this sense, there is no "developer middleman". However, I'm having trouble finding a simple example in Google's docs for a complete login prompt for a user.

Does that mean it is simply missing in the docs or that it is not secure? I mean, Microsoft Excel allows users to directly enter their credentials....is that ok for Google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do OAuth 2 in Apps Script, Spreadsheets and YouTube.

https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/IO2013/YouTubeAnalytics

That is the code accompanying the YouTube API talk at Google I/O. It takes a few mins to setup but you can walk through it.

This video walk through has more details on the setup.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVhsK5jH6u8

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. I would like to skip setting up an OAuth2 producer on my server since there doesn't seem to be a good pyramid/python OAuth2 module out there. Instead, I am hoping that, security-wise, it would be o.k. to skip OAuth2 and send the user credentials from the spreadsheet to my server. thx!

Comment: There is no way to send a user/pass through any API. You can grab and store an access_token/refresh_token for reuse later. You can do that modifying the sample code I pointed out.

Comment: ok. Just wanted to make sure b/f I spent like a sh**tload of time hacking together an OAuth2 producer. Damn. Thanks for your help!